# Problems with Chrome path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and running a html file on my local machine (no server).

The following works on firefox but not on chrome:

```
$('#result').load('test.html');
```

It seem to be something wrong with the path.

Anyone know how to sort this out without having to add an absolute path please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax requests cannot be sent cross-domain. On your local machine, every request is cross-domain to the browser, so no Ajax can be used at all. Chrome is a bit more strict than Firefox here. There is no solution, you will just have to upload it to a web server or install something like Apache on your local machine for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, AJAX requests cannot be sent cross-domain, however, if you're just looking to access a local file, you could try enabling one of Chrome's secret flags. Specifically:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

With any luck, you should be able to get things working by changing your chrome shortcut to the following:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I'm not sure if that flag is enabled in all builds of Chrome (I am presently running chromium 10), but it definitely works: I've been using it to enable file-save access in TiddlyWiki.

Comment: You need to edit the shortcut so that instead of pointing at `chrome.exe` it points to `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`. Just right-click the shortcut, go to properties, and you should be able to make the changes there.